# add reference to a file from a different team project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have 2 team project in Visual Studio that have some shared code between them.

Is it possible to have a reference or some kind of link from 1 team project to the other?

Notice that 1 team project may be mapped to one folder and the other to another folder where they both don't have shared path so that making a relative link wont cut it. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need some version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share binaries, add Team Project 1 output to Team Project 2 Lib/3rd Party folder.

**Team Project 1**

```
$/Project1/Dev/3rdParty/Project2/SomeProduct.Common.dll
```

**Team Project 2**

```
$/Project2/Dev/SomeProduct/SomeProduct.Common/ <-- sources here
```

I you're looking to share code, then I'd advise you to reconsider your source control strategy as you will face either one of the two issues:

1. Managing duplicated source code
2. Syncronizing the same code between different projects

Either way won't lead to anything manageable. Instead invest your efforts towards binary sharing.